# IIS ODBC logging doesn't work - solving "Could not initialize the logging module" problem

Tags: iis, odbc

I'm absolutely new to IIS and hardly know what I'm doing.

I've configured ODBC logging for our IIS server exactly following steps specified by Microsoft on this website: **[support.microsoft.com/kb/245243](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245243)**. When I started browsing on this site, nothing was logged into my database. So I went to event viewer and found an event of number 2271, [**described here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349248(WS.10).aspx).

First I restarted the W3SVC service as described there and after that I couldn't browse my website at all. When I turned the logging off in the properties of website in IIS Manager, everything came back to normal.

Then I proceeded to number 2 - verify if the website is started. Unluckily I found no appcmd app on my computer and nowhere to download it so I tried to check it in IIS Manager. Following Microsoft's steps I found my website's details but there was nothing in the column "Status". In the column "State" kit was "Started", but status was empty. Does it mean that website was not started? Or did Microsoft mean State, not Status? How can I make it work, what can be the problem? I will greatly appreciate help as I'm stuck and it's my first day at work.

Comment: appcmd is a tool introduced with IIS 7 (Windows Server 2008). I suppose you're on Windows Server 2003?

Comment: yesssssssssssss (at least 15 characters)

Comment: Here is a VERY OLD tutorial (written for IIS 5 - Windows Server 2000) http://www.iisfaq.com/default.aspx?View=A151&P=141

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this isn't the answer to your question, but I have a suggestion. ODBC logging isn't considered the best option for production servers, because when it is enabled, IIS disables the HTTP.sys kernel-mode cache degrading overall server performance. Microsoft doesn't recommend ODBC logging unless your database limits you to this option.

You could use [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) for moving your IIS logs to the database or query them directly.

> Log Parser supports different input
>   formats, including all IIS log file
>   formats. Log Parser also supports
>   multiple output formats, such as text
>   files and database tables. You can use
>   Log Parser to filter entries, to
>   convert log files to other formats,
>   and to perform data mining.

---

The eventlog ID you've provided (2271) is probably a sign, that there something wrong with your ODBC connection. I would re-check username/password and the database server's name and address.

If you created the database table "manually", verfify if all the columns which are needed are present in that table.

Comment: yes i know about it but i need odbc